# Adding additional columns to existing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add two columns in a query: `dbo.PROCESSO.dt_cadastro` and `dbo.PROCESSO.dt_encerrado`. The `PROCESSO` and `NUMERO_PROCESSO` tables are related through the column called `cd_processo`.

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT    
  dbo.CLIENTE.ds_razao_social, 
  dbo.COMARCA.ds_comarca,
  dbo.JUIZO.ds_juizo, 
  dbo.COMARCA.ds_sigla_unidade, 
  dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.no_processo
FROM    
  dbo.COMARCA 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO ON 
    dbo.COMARCA.ds_sigla_unidade = dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.ds_sigla_unidade 
    AND dbo.COMARCA.cd_comarca = dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_comarca 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JUIZO ON 
    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.ds_sigla_unidade = dbo.JUIZO.ds_sigla_unidade 
    AND    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_juizo = dbo.JUIZO.cd_juizo 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO ON 
    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_processo = dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO.cd_processo 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CLIENTE ON 
    dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO.cd_cliente = dbo.CLIENTE.cd_cliente
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema for all of the involved tables and an example of what you think the query should look like when you're done?  Can you run that query, show us example results, and tell us how they differ from the results you want?

Comment: You should read up on using aliases. It makes your code a LOT easier to read and three part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT    
  dbo.CLIENTE.ds_razao_social, 
  dbo.COMARCA.ds_comarca,
  dbo.JUIZO.ds_juizo, 
  dbo.COMARCA.ds_sigla_unidade, 
  dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.no_processo,
  dbo.PROCESSO.dt_cadastro,
  dbo.PROCESSO.dt_encerrado
FROM    
  dbo.COMARCA 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO ON 
    dbo.COMARCA.ds_sigla_unidade = dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.ds_sigla_unidade 
    AND dbo.COMARCA.cd_comarca = dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_comarca 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JUIZO ON 
    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.ds_sigla_unidade = dbo.JUIZO.ds_sigla_unidade 
    AND    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_juizo = dbo.JUIZO.cd_juizo 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO ON 
    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_processo = dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO.cd_processo 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CLIENTE ON 
    dbo.CONTRATO_VINCULADO.cd_cliente = dbo.CLIENTE.cd_cliente
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PROCESSO ON 
    dbo.NUMERO_PROCESSO.cd_processo = dbo.PROCESSO.cd_processo
```

It should be noted though that this is based of the information in the query you posted (there was nothing else to base it on). For a more precise answer you'll have to include the table schemas and expected output in your question.